# updating a file that is being used in a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using a variable to store a json file that is used as a reference in my code. i have a code that checks if the variable is outdated or not. if it is outdated, it will be updated from its source.

```
const someFile = require('./something.json')
```

Everytime the file was outdated, the program tries to update it. and it was successful. however, nodejs kept using the old .json file (that has been replaced) as a reference. making my code output an outdated response.

so how can I tell node.js to use the updated file? thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with the `const` keyword, when a value gets assigned to a constant it cannot be changed ([Info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)), just use `let` keyword and your code should work.

**Update**

If both files exist :

```
let someFile= require('./ab.json')

console.log(someFile); // Will Print content of ab.json

someFile= require('./bc')


console.log(someFile); // Will Print content of bc.json
```

But this would only work for already existing files on app start. So for a run time created file you cannot use require for that you need another option like the fs module ([Docs Node 8.x](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback))

**P.S** : While it's valid solution, if the file is a json and gets changed regularly you can just use redis and it's Keyspace Notifications if this is a large scale application if not fs is the way to go.

Comment: i've tried using `let`. and it still don't work. the only way i could get node.js to update the file is to restart node.js

Comment: does the the second file exist before the start of the program of does it get created at run time, if it's run time you cannot use require for this. you would need to use the fs module to read the file.

Comment: the file existed before runtime.

Comment: ah i just see your new update, i will try that first, see how it goes

Comment: Also forgot to mention, files cannot be updated as well in require, only the cached copy before at the start of the app would work

Answer (score 0):

As described in [Require Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching), `require` will cache the file, so even if you update the file and use `require` again to get the file you wont see the changes.

> **Caching**
>
> Modules are cached after the first time they are loaded. This means
>   (among other things) that every call to require('foo') will get
>   exactly the same object returned, if it would resolve to the same
>   file.

Instead can try reading the file each time.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var data = fs.readFileSync('something.json', 'utf8'); 
var someFile = JSON.parse(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

//myjson.json

```
{
    "data": {
        "name": "uday",
        "age": 25
    }
}
```

controller.js

```
var myJSON = require('./myjson.json');
var fs = require('fs');

console.log("before change-->", myJSON);
myJSON.data.age = 26;
console.log("after change-->", myJSON);

fs.writeFileSync('myjson.json', JSON.stringify(myJSON));
```

console result

```
before change--> { data: { name: 'uday', age: 25 } }
after change--> { data: { name: 'uday', age: 26 } }
```